# Is it better to have decode<'T> function or each api should know how to decode/encode itself?

Tags: reflection, encoding, f#, apache-kafka

I'm trying to implement [kafka protocol](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol) in f# and **I would like to know is it worth to use reflection for encode/decode in order to get fast and nice way to add new requests or leave each request to be responsible on it's own to increase performance**

Reflection gives ability to have `Codec.encode` and `Codec.decode<'T>` that are separated from the protocol (classes that represents all requests and responses) and makes adding new requests/responses just by adding more records.
But it slows down encoding/decoding process.

Methods `.Encode()` and `.Decode()` on each request makes it harder to add new requests, it adds more code so more places to get a bug and it hides protocol.

Example:

```
(* just translated from BNF from kafka protocol page *)
type MetadataRequest = {
   TopicName:          string list }
 type RequestType =
   | MetadataRequest of MetadataRequest
   // | ProduceRequest of ProduceRequest
   // ...
 type RequestMessage = {
   ApiKey:             int16
   ApiVersion:         int16
   CorrelationId:      int32
   ClientId:           string
   RequestMessage:     RequestType }
 type Request = {
   Size:               int32
   Message:            RequestMessage }

(* and to use this: *)
// val encode : value:obj -> byte[] option
// val decode : data:byte[] -> 'T option (requires default constructor)
getMetadataRequest [|"topic1"; "topic2"|]
|> Codec.encode
|> connection.send
|> Codec.decode<MetadataResponse>
|> // do something with repsonse
```

Note: I've removed all match option entries to show the idea that should wrap different errors in encoding, sending, decoding

Here is C# example with each request knows how to encode/decode itself: [MetadataRequest.cs](https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net/blob/master/src/kafka-net/Protocol/MetadataRequest.cs) from kafka-net by Jroland

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at FsPickler's serialization concept http://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/overview.html

Comment: yup, that is interesting, will check it out

Comment: FsPickler looks really good and I'll give it a try to see if I can use it and not reimplement the idea behind it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look at FsPickler's serialization concept nessos.github.io/FsPickler/overview.html

Comment: Thanks, FsPickler is the best option I found so far now, it has performance close to direct encode/decode from the object like in kafka-net but much better usability and less code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the code example, `Codec.encode` and `Codec.decode<'a>` are simply two functions composed with the pipeline operator.

This means that any functions that match the types `obj -> byte[] option` and `byte[] -> 'a option` can be used.

I think providing `Codec.encode` and `Codec.decode<'a>` as default mechanisms to enable users to get started quickly would be beneficial.

That design doesn't prevent users with special needs from writing custom encoding/decoding functions that they can compose into the pipeline instead of the default functions.

Thus, based on the limited understanding I have of the problem, I think the current design looks fine, and I'd definitely not recommend making it more object-oriented, which would risk mixing responsibilities that are best kept separate.

Comment: Actually is't not one more binary serialization tool but a helper with kafka api protocol. I want to have easy way to add new api requests in the future when apache kafka release new versions, but yes, I want to have it not too object-oriented as it would be good to have a way to extend serialization to add for example json data from message encoded there.